# Finding inline style with lxml.cssselector

Tags: python, lxml

New to this library (no more familiar with BeautifulSoup either, sadly), trying to do something very simple (search by inline style):

```
<td style="padding: 20px">blah blah </td>
```

I just want to select all tds where style="padding: 20px", but I can't seem to figure it out. All the examples show how to select td, such as:

```
for col in page.cssselect('td'):
```

but that doesn't help me much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that both [Ruslan Spivak](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2619964/190597) and [nosklo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2619712/190597) have given better answers below.

---

```
import lxml.html
data = """<td style="padding: 20px">blah blah </td>
<td style="padding: 21px">bow bow</td>
<td style="padding: 20px">buh buh</td>
"""
doc = lxml.html.document_fromstring(data)
for col in doc.cssselect('td'):
    style = col.attrib['style']
    if style=='padding: 20px':
        print(col.text.strip())
```

prints

```
blah blah
buh buh
```

and manages to skip `bow bow`.

Comment: Thanks! Now all I need is for lxml to actually install on a windows machine, and I'm golden!

Comment: Why `document_fromstring` not just `fromstring`?

Comment: @nn0p: `document_fromstring` returns a `HtmlElement` which begins with `<html>`, `fromstring` returns a `HtmlElement` which begins with `<div>`. In this case it does not matter.

Answer (score 4):

Well, there's a better way: XPath.

```
import lxml.html
data = """<td style="padding: 20px">blah blah </td>
<td style="padding: 21px">bow bow</td>
<td style="padding: 20px">buh buh</td>
"""
doc = lxml.html.document_fromstring(data)
for col in doc.xpath("//td[@style='padding: 20px']"):
    print col.text
```

That is neater and also faster.

Answer (score 3):

If you prefer to use CSS selectors:

```
import lxml.html
data = """<td style="padding: 20px">blah blah </td>
<td style="padding: 21px">bow bow</td>
<td style="padding: 20px">buh buh</td>
"""
doc = lxml.html.document_fromstring(data)
for td in doc.cssselect('td[style="padding: 20px"]'):
   print td.text
```